# How do I force NGINX to add the "Content-Length" header for PHP files

Tags: php, nginx

How do I force NGINX to add the "Content-Length:" header in the response for fastcgi content (We are using PHP-FPM)?

```
# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0

# vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
...
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/opt/remi/php70/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
...
```

We recently switched to CloudFront for our CDN for our dynamic content. CloudFront has an option to compress with gzip but in order for it to work they require the "Content-Length:" header in each response.

I see the "Content-Length" header when NGINX serves image files but not PHP files. I know it's technically possible to use output buffering in PHP and add the header myself but I don't want to edit the code. We have a large website with millions of pages and hundreds of templates.

I know I could easily turn on "gzip" compression in NGINX on our origin server but then we have to have multiple versions of every page on the CDN. Our content changes quickly so I want to make it so once anyone visits a page it's cached. And we don't have to add another request to the origin if the user's accept-encoding request header is different.

Comment: So is it using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`?

Comment: @ficuscr, I did see "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" on NGINX version 1.6 with http/1.1. I upgraded to version 1.14 with http/2. Now I don't see that header

Comment: OK, know if it were set it would be expected that there be no content-length. Sorry all I got. Honestly confused by the question. Why does your CDN care about the NGINX content length? Are you talking about when uploading content to the CDN? Not following.

Comment: From Amazon's documentation for serving files from a custom origin: "The origin must include a Content-Length header in the response so CloudFront can determine whether the size of the file is in the range that CloudFront compresses. If the Content-Length header is missing, CloudFront won't compress the file.". If I have a static html file it works. NGINX includes the content-length header on our origin server and CloudFront compresses it. But dynamic pages don't include this header and don't get compressed.

Comment: I also tried adding the line "chunked_transfer_encoding off;" when using "http/1.1". It removed the "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" header with the old version but again no "Content-Length" header

Comment: Did you ever find resolution to this issue? I have the same one right now, and it's proving to be quite a challenge to figure out.